# Does linux memory cache depend on process PID?

Tags: kernel, process, memory, cache

Does Linux kernel reserve memory cache by process PID or something tied to running instance?

So if I copy process memory cache to another machine, where the same application exists, but not yet started, would this memory cache be utilized or it will be useless on another system?

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544353/100397

Comment: For example with cgroups systemd swappiness to 100% and specify target zram disk, which could be later replicated with drbd.

Comment: What cache are you referring to? The one whose size is displayed by `free`?